# Permission denied Read file on a network drive from php server for which just the user has read access to it

Tags: php, windows, permissions, file-access, network-drive

I want to open a file in a network drives with php. The file is not accessible for every one, just for one user.
I have the following code:

```
        $file = "$dir/$fileName";
        $fp = fopen($file, "r");
        if ( !$fp ) {
            throw new Exception('File open failed.');
        }
        $str = stream_get_contents($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        exit;
```

The result: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: What user has read access to it? Is it the logged in user on the Windows machine or the user that's running the web server? When running PHP through a web server, it's the web server user that needs the access.

Comment: Not the logged in user on windows and not the web server user. While adding the network, I connected to a shared folder on a completely another server with completely another credentials!

Comment: So why do you expect the account operating the http server to be able to access then?

Comment: Ah ok I thought if the driver is accessible by any user in the desktop, I can open any file with php.
So I need to give access to the web server user, right? I use xampp web server, where to find which user I use? Please excuse my ignorance

Comment: Can I get any help??